# G. Washington notes on geometry

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, nachlasse

Do you know if  there is a pdf file containing President George Washington's notes on geometry and surveying somewhere in the Internet?

I recall reading a few weeks ago that those notes had been recently made publicly available by the Library of Congress but I could not find a single file containing all of them in the relevant site:

https://www.loc.gov/resource/mgw1a.002/?sp=2

If it is actually not possible to have these notes in a single pdf file, do you know of an expert on President Washington that has written about what it is that we are to find in those manuscripts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The historian of mathematics Fred Rickey (West Point) may have some information of use to you. He is a scholar who has published [multiple papers on George Washington's notes](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Fred-Rickey). If a complete version of Washington's notes is available online, Fred Rickey might well know how to find it.